# Merge lists without ordering and not eliminating duplicates

Tags: python

(Python) I have 2 lists and want to merge them as follows.

```
a = [2,5,1]
b = [4,2,2]
```

Combine lists and the expected output should be: [2,5,1,4,2,2]

Comment: For future reference, the term you're looking for is "concatenate", not "merge"

Comment: Assuming [nneonneo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1204143/nneonneo) helped you, you should upvote and check-mark him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `+`:

```
a + b
```

This will create a new list which is the concatenation of the two input lists.

Comment: It's times like these that I wish there wasn't a minimum character count :)

Answer (score 0):

There is *also* the extend function, this simply extends `a` with `b`:

```
a = [2,5,1]
b = [4,2,2]
a.extend(b)
```

To make a new list, eg: `c` one can do something like the following, even though nneonneo answer is simpler..:

```
def extendList(a, b):
    a.extend(b)
    return a

a = [2,5,1]
b = [4,2,2]
c = extendList(a, b)
```

Comment: (Note that `extendList` will mutate the first list that is passed in, and `a is c` afterwards).

Comment: `a is c` will be `True` after `c = extendList(a, b)`. This means that alterations to `a` will affect `c`, and vice-versa, because they are the same list. This may be problematic in some cases, or beneficial in others.

Comment: I understod that part. But i'm extending `a` with `b` in a private scope (within a function), so it should not be global, but for some reason (i do not understand) this does in fact alter `a` outside the function.